# Best practice for formatting/building queries to execute in a pl/sql stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, binding, plsql

Which method is preferred/faster/best practice?  Does the second example execute *slower*?  I assume it may, because the query has not been "compiled" yet since it is passed as a concatenated string before it is executed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_FAST(
        VI_OBID IN NUMBER,
        VO_NAME OUT VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT NAME
    INTO VO_NAME
    FROM BILLING.CUSTOMER
    WHERE OBJECTID = VI_OBID;
    --    dbms_output.put_line('VI_OBID: '||VI_OBID||']');
    --    dbms_output.put_line('VO_NAME: ['||VO_NAME||']');
END SP_FAST;
```

Or this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_NOTASFAST(
        VI_OBID IN NUMBER,
        VO_NAME OUT VARCHAR)
AS
    qstring VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN

    qstring:=   'SELECT NAME ' ||    
                'FROM BILLING.CUSTOMER    ' ||
                'WHERE OBJECTID = :1';

    execute immediate qstring into VO_NAME using VI_OBID;

    --    dbms_output.put_line('VI_OBID: '||VI_OBID||']');
    --    dbms_output.put_line('VO_NAME: ['||VO_NAME||']');
END SP_NOTASFAST;
```

Comment: First one definitely.

Comment: use static sql statement when you do not need a dynamic sql statement, it is quicker

Comment: There is another option that might be in the middle: the `DBMS_SQL` package. See comparison here: http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/231.dbms-sql-vs-execute-immediate.aspx and section _Native Dynamic SQL is Faster than DBMS_SQL_ here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm#26586

Answer (score 0):

Each method has advantages and disadvantages.

The following link will be very useful for you. This chapter address how coding dynamic SQL in Oracle database.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dynamic_sql.htm